# R file does not generate variable name

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-resources

I am creating an android application and when changing some of the code and going to run it I got told that there was an error in the application's R.Java file. For some reason a variable name is not generated.

```
public static final class id { 
public static final int  =0x7f09018d;
public static final int BetweenTicks=0x7f090000;
public static final int Bottom=0x7f09000b;
}
```

The project contains no errors and I tried cleaning it multiple times.

I had two views with the same id, say view_id. I changed one of the two id to view_id_1 and I think that is when the error started happening. I deleted the view_id-1 and there is only one view now. However, I still get the error.

Comment: Have you thought about just adding it manually?

Comment: adding it manually will have no success, the R. file is generated automatically, everything changed by user will be overwritten

Comment: You should post the xml layout, if the R. file is not correctly working, the most issues are mistakes in layout files..-

Answer (score 0):

Happened because of

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/   "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:textColor="@color/button_gray"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Comment: Yes, it is all fine now.

Comment: It does not let me do that yet.

Comment: nobody can mark his own answer as correct. I think in that case, it´s just a simple mistake, not really a tricky thing...

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two views with the same ID.
every time you fix an error in this type an error that makes your File R disappear
you need to `clean` your workspace and some time also to `rebuild` your Project.